# Tab Bar Controller item image not showing

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am using xcode 8

I have a simple Tab Bar Controller, I changed the Tab Bar Item image in each View Controller that embedded inside Tab Bar Controller:

[image]

However in storyboard, the tab bar item images on Tab Bar Controller doesn't change. When I rum my app, the Tab Bar Controller shows only text without any image at all. What is wrong?

This is on emulator:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you have set  `Selected Image` of `Tab Bar Item` instead of `Image` of the `Bar Item`.

You could use `Selected Image` to change the `Bar Item` image when user click over it.

[image]

Comment: You are right! What is "Selected Image" of Tab Bar Item then?